# Did Christian Bale star in "A Midsummer Night's Dream" (1981)?

Tags: casting, a-midsummer-nights-dream

Christian Bale is said to be in the BBC's 1981 production of *A Midsummer Night's Dream*. However, after watching it over and over again. I can't find him. I think he is one of the little boys but I am not sure, I need help please :)

I know he was in the 1999 version of *A Midsummer Night's Dream*. ! However, my theatre professor said that he is in the 1981 version too. I think he may be an extra because there's no credit ... Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Are you able to ask your theatre professor where he got the info from?

Answer (score 5):

#### Doesn't look like it!

Neither [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000288/?ref_=sr_1) or any other source that I've been able to find state that Christian Bale appeared in the 1981 Midsummer Night Dreams. However as you and all of the articles that I can find state, he did later appear in the 1999 version with the same name.

Comment: If he was an extra, he wouldn't appear in IMDB - so your answer is 'correct' in that I'm sure you haven't seen a source, but its still unproven as its a very hard thing to prove.